# Error deploying .war file from Nexus to Wildfly using Docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, jboss, wildfly

I'm encountering an error while trying to deploy a .war file from Nexus to Wildfly using Docker.

The error message is:

```
10:13:56,319 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "file.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"file.war\".component.\"javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener\".WeldInstantiator" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener
    Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet and javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet$NoBodyAsyncContextListener disagree on InnerClasses attribute"}}
```

I've attempted the following troubleshooting steps, but without success:

1. Removing the javax.servlet dependency from pom.xml.
2. Adding a section exclusion (ch.qos.logback) within the dependency org.springframework.boot.

The versions I'm currently using in my pom.xml are:
Java version 11
Vaadin version 23.0.1
Wildfly Maven Plugin version 4.0.0.Final

In my Dockerfile, I'm using the following:
JDK 11
Wildfly 15.0.1.Final
MSSQL_JDBC_VERSION 12.4.2.jre11

Answer (score 1):

For a error like this you need to find your Wildfly JavaEE version which is:

WildFly 15 supports Java EE 8. This means it implements the specifications defined in Java EE 8, including Servlet 4.0, JPA 2.2, CDI 2.0, JSF 2.3, and others.

Then just depend on

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>8.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

That is all you need for most cases.

And use JavaEE APIs in your classes. Then mismatch errors will disappear. And if it is not a legacy app try using most recent version for Wildfly and Jakarta APIs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the issue was a bit different. 

I had to create a profile in my pom.xml for docker with the dependencies (spring-boot-starter-web and tomcat-dbcp with version 9.0.30) and changed MSSQL_JDBC_VERSION=12.4.2.jre8